What do these expressions mean in NASA's Steve Stitch's brief Starliner undocking statement?
After about 00:30 in The BBC's September 7, 2024 Boeing Starliner returns to earth without astronauts | BBC News, there's a clip of Steve Stitch, Manager, NASA Commercial Crew Program reading a brief statement.
I've taken the automatically generated YouTube transcript and done my best to make some small edits for clarity only:

I'm happy to report Starliner did really well today in the undock, deorbit and landing sequence. We used the NASA docking system for the second time on the mission to undock from the space station. That system performed really well. It's a derivative system, will be used for Orion down the road, so it was good to pave the way for Orion as well.
The spacecraft executed a nominal breakout sequence -- the first time we've used that -- to back away from the station. We backed out to about 5 meters, and then did a series of about twelve burns using the service module forward jets. And then we opened -- after that sequence of maneuvers -- we ended up opening at about twenty two kilometers per rev away from the space station.
All those thrusters did really well through that step sequence, no problems at all.

This brief statement was likely worded for "space reporters" and not the general public. But I'd like to ask for some brief clarifications nonetheless.

What comprises the "NASA docking system" and what does it mean that it is a "derivative system"? That it was derived from something, or will Orion's be derived from it, or both?
What are "burns" of the "forward jets"? Are these also called thrusters, or are they something different?
What does "opening at about twenty two kilometers per rev away from the space station" mean? Is that a slightly higher or lower orbit and the 22 km/rev is its de-phases or opening rate?



"NASA docking system" is an implementation of the International Docking System Standard used on the Node 2 Forward and Node 2 Zenith International Docking Adapters.  Orion and Gateway and HLS will ultimately implement derivatives of the same standard; it's not clear to me how much they'll change from the International Docking Adapters, if at all. There is some wiggle room in the standard, but less than there should be imo.

The jets are also called thrusters, yes.

It's a slightly lower orbit ultimately. CST's initial departure was forward and high, taking it over top of and behind the station, but after that it's low and forward. That 22km/rev rate is once it's passed below and in front of the station.



BlobbyMcBlobby's post is rapidly expanding and has already eclipsed mine in quality; I don't think I have much more to offer so in the coming days I might delete my answer. We'll see. If anyone wants references for the CST departure trajectory I think the near-field should be pretty evident in any of the video; far field is just "it has to be below ISS because it's going to land eventually, and lower orbits have shorter periods and so will go forward"

Please keep it! - yours answers the third question I couldn't catch! Mine was going to be left as 'partial' because of that - yours has the complete picture!

@blobbymcblobby lol I figured you'd get there eventually.  Well if nobody else gets to CST--which I wish I had a good picture of but RPOP wasn't on the six-pack (nine pack now? I think it got expanded?) this time--I'll leave it

The International Docking Adapter is not the same thing as the NASA Docking System. It's specifically an adapter to convert an APAS-95 docking port to the passive side of an IDSS interface. Artemis missions will implement a "block 2" version of NDS

@Tristan is Block 2 NDS still in development?  What I meant was it wasn't clear to me how NDS will change, and that still isn't clear to me so I'll hold off on an edit til it's a little more substantive.

@ErinAnne I'm actually not sure if it's still under development or if it's nearly done.  I've only been very peripherally involved (as in sitting near someone who was working on it)

@Tristan I was involved with items on the periphery of IDA (the PDT; actually a CDT design too but that was never used afaik) but I only hear the Gateway stuff through the RPOC grapevine now, and thus only about target problems if there are any

partial addressing:
The terms "thruster" and "jet" appear to be interchangeable terms used to mean generally the same thing:

https://www.apr.org/news/2024-06-22/nasa-delays-landing-of-the-problem-filled-starliner-capsule-until-july
Starliner has a series of chemically fueled thrusters in a compartment attached to the crew capsule called the Service Module. A test firing of the jets on the vehicle showed they’re overheating, possibly due to the frequency of the thrusts, or “burns,” that are needed to return the astronauts safely to the Earth.

or

https://www.nasa.gov/news-release/nasa-commercial-partner-boeing-tests-cst-100-spacecraft-thrusters-2/
test firings of its steering jets
The tests assessed how the thrusters — which fire with 1,500 pounds of force
the OMAC thrusters were fired in a vacuum chamber that simulated the space-like environment at an altitude of 100,000 feet. These evaluations put the thrusters through the burns and stresses they would encounter during a real flight. Engineers equipped the jets with a host of instruments to measure changes in the smallest components.

Low Impact Docking System (LIDS) was something that NASA was looking at from the 80s through to the 90s, towards the end it was part of the X-38 program. When that program went, it went on to become part of another program, Constellation. In 2010 the International Docking System Standard was formed to standardize docking adapters, and NASA developed its NDS - NASA Docking System - from what used to be known as LIDS to conform to the new IDS Standard.
Once the Shuttle program was over, the PMA docking collars were adapted to the new IDSS by adding a 'new front porch' on to the PMA, the  International Docking Adapter (IDA), that implements the passive version of the NDS.
Dragon and Starliner implement the active side of the NDS to dock with the IDA on the PMA on the ISS.
Orion has the NDS and the Gateway Lunar station will be equipped with it and ESA has its own implementation but compatible version of the IDSS.
So in terms of derivative, you can say that NDS is derived from LIDS.
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20170001546/downloads/20170001546.pdf
http://dockingstandard.nasa.gov/Documents/AIAA_ATS_NDS-IDSS_Overview_Draft1.pdf oops https://web.archive.org/web/20111015075220/http://dockingstandard.nasa.gov/Documents/AIAA_ATS_NDS-IDSS_Overview_Draft1.pdf
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20090007783/downloads/20090007783.pdf
https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20180004167/downloads/20180004167.pdf
additional:

The NDS Block 1 includes
provisions for capture, structural attachment, power/data transfer, and undocking. It uses a direct-drive
electromechanical Stewart Platform capture system architecture, along with an innovative automated
control scheme, to achieve an unprecedented level of performance and simplicity. Its design implements
the new International Docking System Standard, which will be a key enabler of diverse and flexible
exploration missions. NDS qualification was completed in 2017 to support a planned first flight in 2018 on
the Boeing CST-100 Starliner.



NASA’s newest docking system evolved from systems developed during the Apollo-Soyuz Test Project. The last US built docking
system, flew in support of the ASTP, and following this NASA commissioned the Space Division of North American Rockwell to conduct trade
studies on docking technologies used.


Interface Definitions Document for using, installing, and interfacing to the NDS Block 1 that will enable successful docking to the IDA (ISS):

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20150014481/downloads/20150014481.pdf
For clarity, SpaceX, as an independent commercial contractor, built its own IDSS compliant docking ring with active (moving) hooks that enable it to latch onto the static (passive) hooks of the IDA, that is permanently attached to the PMA of the ISS.
Boeing, as a NASA contractor for the NDS, built this as part of the Starliner anyway, and is therefore naturally IDSS compliant. AFAIK both Starliner and Dragon lack the parts that allow them to be passive.
Going by NASA's documents, the history of its NDS goes all the way back to the days of the Apollo-Soyuz Test Project in 1975, LIDS of the Orbital Spaceplane Program in the 1990s, through to Starliner, and on to Orion (and Lunar Gateway).

good LIDS/NDS/IDSS summary!

Is IDS derived from the androgynus docking system already thought up during the apollo days?

@TrySCE2AUX I think you can trace the lineage back into APAS but that might just be carcinization. Maybe everything evolves to a three-petal androgynous docking interface eventually?

@ErinAnne :D.. like everything evolves into a crab eventually? But I think you're on to something. At least if you want a (more or less) symmetric system where you can dock sinilar systems in any combination.

@TrySCE2AUX I think that the power and data stuff in IDSS might make it all non-androgynous anyway but I'm not 100% sure on that. I think there are some open questions still on how HLS is going to be handled because suddenly there's a vehicle that's target sometimes (for Orion rendezvous iirc) and chaser sometimes (for rendezvous with Gateway) which makes me laugh when I hear about it because it's like... this was foreseeable

Funny, thinking about it, I recall seeing a mini version of APAS, doing what LIDS/SIMAC was meant to do, on what was to be the docking system for SSF quite a while ago.
